# DataNucleus + JPA [ComposedIdKey]

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I´m using DataNucleus JPA and I have a class with a composite key.
The idea is create a composed Key for persitented in Hbase.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ComposedIdKey.class)

public class Customer_test {
    @Id
    public String firstName;
    @Id
    public String lastName;
    @Id
    public String dateOfBirth;
```

and i create a class ComposedIdKey

```
public class ComposedIdKey implements Serializable
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String dateOfBirth;

    public ComposedIdKey ()
    {
    }

     public ComposedIdKey(String value)
    {
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer (value, "::");
        token.nextToken();               // className
        this.firstName = token.nextToken(); // field1
        this.lastName = token.nextToken(); // field2l
        this.dateOfBirth = token.nextToken(); // filed3
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == this)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof ComposedIdKey))
        {
            return false;
        }
        ComposedIdKey c = (ComposedIdKey)obj;

        return firstName.equals(c.firstName) && lastName.equals(c.lastName) && dateOfBirth.equals(c.dateOfBirth);
    }

    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return this.firstName.hashCode() ^ this.lastName.hashCode() ^ this.dateOfBirth.hashCode() ;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        // Give output expected by String constructor
        return this.getClass().getName() + "::"  + this.firstName + "::" + this.lastName + "::" + this.dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

**I have this error:**

*Class DN_Schema.Customer has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class DN_Schema.Customer has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.*

Comment: The message refers to class *Customer* yet you present *Customer_test*. Also you chopped off the stack trace

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton